# Performance issue with EF Include

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-5

iI'm in a project where I do not have any controll over the database structure. I've created my model from the Database and there are foreign keys on all tables below. Apart from the user tables, there are about 500k to 1000k rows in each table and they are quite wide.

Executing this query with EF5 takes over two seconds:

```
 var customerEngage = ctx.Customer_TB
                        .Include(c => c.Insurance_TB)
                        .Include(c => c.Insurance_TB.Select(i => i.H80Row_TB))
                        .Include(c => c.Insurance_TB.Select(i => i.WinsureRow_TB))
                        .Include(c => c.Insurance_TB.Select(i => i.User_TB))
                        .Include(c => c.Insurance_TB.Select(i => i.User_TB.Department_TB))
                        .SingleOrDefault(c => c.IDCustomer == myID);
```

There aren't neccessarily any rows in the related tables.

I can do this SQL query without any performance issues:

```
SELECT * 
from dim.Customer_TB c
    INNER JOIN fact.insurance_tb i on i.IDCustomer = c.IDCustomer
    LEFT JOIN fact.H80Row_TB h80 on h80.IDInsurance = i.IDInsurance
    LEFT JOIN fact.WinsureRow_TB winsure on winsure.IDInsurance = i.IDInsurance
    LEFT JOIN eb.User_TB a on i.LockedByUserID = a.IDUser
    LEFT JOIN eb.Department_TB dept on dept.IDDepartment = a.IDDepartment
WHERE c.IDCustomer = myID
```

Firstly, am I doing something wrong with my EF query? I could make an SP, but how would I fill my POCOS from that result set?

Comment: I have seen this happen across many ORMs.. and it is generally because of a type mismatch. Generally they have been `varchar` to `nvarchar`. The ORM selects are executed as `sp_executesql` calls and the implicit conversions in those calls make the query run for an incredible amount of time. If you can start a SQL Trace and capture the actual query being sent.. you'll notice it yourself, even when you run the same query from management studio.

Comment: Yes. It takes for ever if I run the query from the SQL Trace as well. Any idea what I can do about it?

Comment: @Simon it is pretty unusual to see any `sp_executesql` from an ORM - since the ORM can construct and execute ad-hoc command-text trivially, and there is a vexing limit to the size of commands that `sp_executesql` will accept; `sp_executesql` is seen more commonly when a stored procedure needs to execute sql that it constructs on-the-fly (a "search" proc that accepts multiple criteria, for example)

Comment: Actually I've changed the search criteria and the produced SQL is fast so it must be somehting with the type mismatch you mentioned.

Comment: @MarcGravell I have seen both NHibernate and EF queries executed on the server as `sp_executesql` with the trace open.. do you know what causes that?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead It's the case here.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead ah, but the trace data is often a white lie ;p It is also entirely possible that it is *representing* it like that so that you can copy and paste it into SSMS - which is hard to do for parameterized queries. For queries without parameters, sure: just display them "as is". If it faked it with `declare @...` statements, it would hit a different execution plan cache entry - so in order to be copy/paste-able, *and* include the parameter values, *and* hit the same cache: it **lies** and pretends that there is an `sp_executesql`

Comment: I should note that db-level stuff isn't really my strong suit! So I honestly don't know what causes an ORM to use `sp_executesql`..

Comment: @Marc Awesome! Just another one of those little things I was unaware of. Cheers!

Comment: @SimonWhitehead in other news, it also says that a connection-reset command was issued: actually, this is performed via a bit-flag in the TDS protocol stream. The tracer/profiler *represents* this by displaying the equivalent TSQL commands: but they were never actually issued as commands.

Comment: @Marc Interesting.. where is your source for this? Surely not  MSDN..

Answer (score 0):

Change your SingleOrDefault to a Where - your SingleOrDefault isn't the same, it's ensuring at most one row.

You can also check the sql being issued with Sql Profiler and/or `var sql = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)customerEngage).ToTraceString();`

Comment: It was a where before, but I'm trying to narrow the problem down, so now I'm just searching the primary key which is unique. It will only be one row. 

I've run Sql Profiler and the produced SQL takes for ever to run.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need all those includes.

```
var customerEngage = ctx.Customer_TB
                        .SingleOrDefault(c => c.IDCustomer == myID);
```

should do the job.

Comment: Even if lazy loading is disabled?

Comment: Yes, thats quick, but I need the data in the included tables :)

Comment: You have it. For instance, just write customerEngage.H80Row_TB.